# Records not grouped by the group by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have this following table:

**pkey - pval**

```
one - dfgf
two - dg 
three - asf
one - asarset
three - se
```

The query

```
select pkey,pval from dummy11 group by pkey,pval
```

returns the following output..

```
pkey  -    pval
three  -   asf
one   -   asarset
three -    se
one   -   dfgf
two    -  dg
```

Why is it not `grouped by pkey,pval` ?

I want the output as how it comes by using `order by`

```
select pkey,pval from dummy11 order by pkey,pval
```

But isn't that the same thing as using `group by` in this case?

Comment: **SHOW** us the input and desired output. `GROUP BY` and `ORDER` are different. Explain in words what you are trying to do.

Comment: Based on your input/output they are grouped by the `group by` clause. You need to read more about grouping by.

Comment: It **is** "grouped" by `pkey,pval` - it's just not *ordered* by those columns. A `group by` does ***not*** sort the output. That's what `order by` is for. The ***only*** way to get a result in a desired order is to use `order by`. Any order you see *without* an `order by` is just by coincident.

Answer (score 0):

```
Why is it not grouped by pkey,pval ?
```

Ans: It is grouped by, you were expecting something that `GROUP BY` doesn't do.

```
I want the output as how it comes by using order by

select pkey,pval from dummy11 order by pkey,pval
But isn't that the same thing as using group by in this case?
```

Ans: NO, it is NOT the same thing. `ORDER BY` sorts the output, `GROUP BY` does NOT sort the output

A `GROUP BY` clause:

```
"groups a result into subsets that have matching values for one or more columns. "
```

[oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html)